# How to deal with type name clashes in Scala?

Tags: scala, scope

I'm writing a class that extends from `Scanners` which forces me to define the type `Token`:

```
object MyScanner extends Scanners {
  type Token = ...
}
```

The problem is that my token class itself is called `Token`:

```
abstract class Token(...)
case class Literal(...)
...
```

Is it in Scala somehow possible to define the type `Token` of `Scanners` to my `Token` class?

`type Token = Token` obviously doesn't work.

I also tried using the whole package name (which begins with `main.scala`) like this:

```
type Token = main.scala....Token
```

This is another name clash as I have defined a `main` function inside `MyScanner`.

My current solution is to rename my token class. Is there another one where I can keep the initial name?

Comment: Another solution would be to rename the lexical 'Type' in 'MyScanner' to 'MyScannerType' (or similar).

Comment: Names you access via `import` may be renamed: `import org.foo.bar.{This => That}` means import `org.foo.bar.This` but renamed to `That`. You can also discard a name, effectively subtracting it from a wild-card import: `import org.foo.bar.{Florp => _, _}`. This imports every symbol from `org.foob.bar` _except_ `Florp`.

Comment: This is a valuable question, so thanks for asking it, but I'd also like to note that if you followed the [Scala naming conventions](http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/naming-conventions.html), you would be able to refer to a package named com.foo.main without having to resort to any tricks. Simple class names are a good idea, but package names should be unique enough that no other organization and no other project within your organization would use the same fully-qualified name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Defining the Token type using a fully qualified class name works.  To avoid the name clash with your main method, you can use the *root* prefix to indicate that you are referring to a fully qualified type name, not a relative type name nor a method name.  For example:

```
package main

import scala.util.parsing.combinator.lexical._

case class Token(s: String)

object MyScanner extends Scanners {
  type Token = _root_.main.Token
  val Token = _root_.main.Token
  def errorToken(msg: String) = Token(msg)
  def token = ???
  def whitespace = ???

  def main = ???
}
```

Some other alternatives include:

1. Defining a type alias outside of the MyScanner object (either in an enclosing object or in a package object).
2. Importing your token class and aliasing it as part of import.  For example: `import main.scala.{Token => MyToken}`.

Comment: Didn't know that about `_root_`. And I'm probably going to use alternative number 2. Thank you.