# Why BsonObjectId::apply(String) method does not work for the second time?

Tags: mongodb, scala

```
//Below line of code works fine with the result, 
//maxBSONValue: org.mongodb.scala.bson.BsonObjectId = BsonObjectId{value=572865049229f27baf82c974}
val maxBSONValue = org.mongodb.scala.bson.BsonObjectId("572865049229f27baf82c974") 

//Subsequent execution of below line results in error
//error: org.mongodb.scala.bson.BsonObjectId.type does not take parameters
val minBSONValue = org.mongodb.scala.bson.BsonObjectId("572865049229f27baf82c96f")
```

Why BsonObjectId::apply(String) method does not work for the second time?

Comment: Additional Info: Creating a method like this works all the time, def getBsonObjectIdValue(v:String) = org.mongodb.scala.bson.BsonObjectId(v)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of invoking `apply()` method from the `BsonObjectId` companion object ([here](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-scala-driver/blob/b9590cecc17e27fe8b97dc96554df27ebdae5479/bson/src/main/scala/org/mongodb/scala/bson/BsonValue.scala#L335)), it seems to be seeing `BsonObjectId` as a type (defined [here](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-scala-driver/blob/b9590cecc17e27fe8b97dc96554df27ebdae5479/bson/src/main/scala/org/mongodb/scala/bson/package.scala#L100)) and it complains that it doesn't take parameters (which is true). This is the cause of your error message. Not sure why it's happening though. Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15453247/how-to-deal-with-type-name-clashes-in-scala) and see if you can find something useful (I didn't really dig too deep into it).

Sorry for posting as answer even though it isn't really one, but I think it could put you on the right track and I couldn't fit it into comments.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort! I indeed saw the code but not sure why compiler is not seeing the companion object's apply method ?

Comment: Well, it's really weird if it's just that snippet you gave us. In case they are at different places in the code (especially different classes) make sure there are no extra imports. I had a similar error today due to my IDE automatically importing scala.collection in the middle of my code so I had a clash between Map comp object and scala.Map type (shortand for scala.collection.immutable.Map)

Comment: Start by examining the exact type of both BsonObjectIds in your IDE/REPL.